# How to prompt user to enable debugging in the bash option?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to prompt the user whether he wants to start debugging or not. How do I do that without adding `-x` myself just after `#!/bin/bash` or without hardcoding it into the script?

Comment: You can use `set -x`, and wrap that in a condition that checks the user input?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155570 this can help

Comment: @BenjaminW. I thought of using set -x and set +x somewhere in the script as well by wrapping it in a condition. I might be reading the question a little too much. I thought I could do it like this `#!/bin/bash -x` by using a condition, but that seems to be a little complicated. I'm trying to prompt the user to enter 0 or 1. If he chooses 1, then it simply turns it on and move on.

Comment: Or, you can call the script with the option.  eg, instead of `./myscript`, call `bash -x myscript`

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin W suggested, just wrap `set -x` in a condition:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enable debugging? " debugmode
case "$debugmode" in
    1|y|Y|yes|YES ) set -x ;;
esac
```

Comment: So much for all those bash tutorials that cautiont `set -x` must immediately follow `#!/bin/bash` `:)`

Comment: Nope, you can do it anywhere in the script, you just won't get a trace of what's before it. I often troubleshoot by adding `set -x` right before a problem section, and `set +x` after it, so the stuff I want a trace of isn't buried among everything else the script does.

Comment: Yes, that is a very good way to narrow the debug output to just a section of a script that is of concern. My comment was a bit in jest, as I recall 20 years ago reading the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide put out by TLDP and recall it making a big point of `set -x` needed to immediately follow the `#!/bin/bash`. Of course as you note, the `set +/- opt` can be used anywhere within the script -- but I recall for a while after reading ABS and before making it to the `set` command  in the `"SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS"` section of `man bash`, I thought that was a requirement `:)`

Answer (score 0):

One trick I often do, is to have on top of my scripts something like

```
[[ ${DEBUG_S:-no} == yes ]] && set -x
```

To run a program `P` with this type of debugging turned on, I do a

```
DEBUG_S=yes P
```

Even if the script is not `P` itself, but a subprocess of `P`, it would turn on the tracing.